# Sum of Matching Columns Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have CSV file with the following data where I need to match column 1 products and get their total sum based on the quantity in column 2:

```
red shirt    1
blue shirt   1
red shirt    1
```

The result should be:

```
red shirt    2
blue shirt   1
```

Below is what I have so far, but I think it's just adding the matched rows together instead of using the sum in column 2.

```
df = pd.read_csv('inventory.csv', names=['product','quantity'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
df1['quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['quantity'],errors='coerce')
df1 = df1.groupby('product')['quantity'].sum()
df1.to_csv(r'inventory_sum.csv')
```

Comment: Likely one of your `product`s has a trailing space, etc.

Comment: By "adding the matched rows together" you mean counting? if not, what's the difference between adding values and summing them?

Comment: Check for whitespace, use `df1.to_dict()` and see if you have leading, trailing or extra spaces in product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection.Counter() as documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

```py
df = pd.read_csv('inventory.csv', names=['product','quantity'])
cnt = Counter()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
   cnt[row['product']] += row['quantity']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
df = pd.read_csv('inventory.csv', names=['product','quantity'])
df1 = df.copy()
# you don't need floats, but ints
# df1['quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['quantity'],errors='coerce')
df1.iloc[:, 1] = df1.iloc[:, 1].astype(int)
df1 = df1.groupby("product").sum()
```

or

```py
df1 = df1.groupby("product").agg({"quantity": "sum"})
```

If all quantities are 1, you can just count

```py
df1 = df1.groupby("product").count()
```

result:

```
            quantity
product             
blue shirt         1
red shirt          2
```